# Location services not working in my macOS Application

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, core-location

Location services not working in my macOS Application though I have enabled it
Below is my swift code:

```
        @IBAction func locateMe(_ sender: Any) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        if #available(OSX 10.14, *) {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        } 
        else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            print("enabled")

            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
        else{

    print("Disabled")
        }

    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error:: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
//        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation();
    }
```

here disabled is printed
But I have enabled location in system preferences as shown in picture below
[image]

Comment: Set the delegate of the location manager to the class.

Comment: done already bro